# How to select a dynamic following DOM element of a DOM element? (css selector)

Tags: html, css, dom

html:

```
<div>Hello</div
<my-custom-el>content</my-custom-el>
```

The `<my-custom-el>` can be once `<my-custom-el>`, other time `<his-custom-el>` etc...

Is there a way to css select the element after the `<div>`, without knowing what DOM element type will be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, with the combination of adjacent sibling ("neighbor") selector `+` and universal selector `*`:

```
div + * { }
```

This will select *any* element that *immediately* follows any `div` element in the DOM, where immediately means that both elements must have the same parent element.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VilleKoo/g3b283wt/)

Comment: It seems to work exactly like native html DOM elements.