# Get all specific children from two parents CSS

Tags: html, css, forms, css-selectors

I want to select all the `input[type=text]` children from two different parent classes.

Which is the cleanest way to do this for the css below?

```
.secciones * input[type=text]
.subsecciones * input[type=text] {
    border: none transparent;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should drop the wildcard selector. You almost never want that, as it is a very broad selector:

```
.secciones input[type=text],
.subsecciones input[type=text] {
    border: none transparent;
    background-color: white;
}
```

---

Css gets parsed from right to left, so this: `.secciones input[type=text]`:
- Select all `input[type=text]`
- For each match filter: check of it is a (grand) child of `.secciones`

```
<div class="secciones">
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="I will match as one of my parents is .secciones" />
    </div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="I will match as one of my parents is .secciones" />
</div>
```

---

If you add the wildcard selector, you basically say "check if `input[type=text]` is a child of *anything*. With the `*` as the most right selector, you start with "select *everything*", which is a lot.

If you want the *direct children* of a selector, you can do this: `.secciones >input[type=text]`:
- Select all `input[type=text]`
- For each match filter: check of it is a *direct* child of `.secciones`

```
<div class="secciones">
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="I will NOT match, my direct parent is NOT .secciones" />
    </div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="I will match, my DIRECT parent is .secciones" />
</div>
```

---

An example of when you might want to use a `*`: `.hideNextElement + *`:

```
<div class="hideNextElement">click me to show next</div>
<div>I can be ANY element. With some JS I can become visible.</div>
```

Comment: When is the use of the `*` recommended, then?

Comment: Sometimes you have to, there are alway exceptions. But you should alwyas treat is as expection

Comment: I've seen * used as a 'reset' rule to set all margins and padding to 0 and things like that, to override any browser defaults. Apart from that I can think of very few reasons to use it, as it becomes really inefficient the more complex a page gets. If I find myself thinking I may need to use * I see that as a smell of something larger that needs addressing rather than 'covering up', but other peoples mileage may vary

Comment: Not using the `*` will (in this case) do exactly the same, but you skip a step in the parse-loop which does "Also check if this element is the child of *anything*", which it always is (with the exception of the html tag)

Comment: @StevenBrookes here's a good use case for the wildcard selector https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41036342/how-to-select-a-dinamic-following-dom-element-of-a-dom-element-css-selector/41036424#41036424

Comment: Yes, that is a good example, added a similar to my answer instead of my previous, thanks

Comment: @VilleKoo That does seem like a valid use of it yes :) Though I would argue that if you have control over the elements that should appear next to the other element, then why are they not wrapped in a known element so the * isn't required? I understand there would be cases where this may not be possible though (distributed teams for example)

Comment: You counter your counterexample: Maintainability. I want to add an element and not worry about 7 other selectors I might want to ypdate. Yes, the wildcard isnt optimal, but in the end, your code should be maintanable without headackes

Comment: I see your point there, but if your team is in charge of how things are displayed, would you not dictate that all content would be inside say, a div? so yes, you can still have whatever custom elements inside, but we know there is one element that will wrap that content. I guess its a case of striking a balance of things such as performance, maintainability etc which keeps us coming back for more!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use *`*`*.
Instead, use *`,`*. You should do it something like:

```
.secciones input[type=text],
.subsecciones input[type=text] {
    border: none transparent;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to target all descendants of `.secciones` and `.subsecciones`, you can use the [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) :

```
.secciones input[type=text],
.subsecciones input[type=text] {
    border: none transparent;
    background-color: white;
}
```

If you want to target only the direct descentants (the children) of `.secciones` and `.subsecciones`, you can use the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) :

```
.secciones > input[type=text],
.subsecciones > input[type=text] {
    border: none transparent;
    background-color: white;
}
```

You could read more about using combinators [at the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors).

Comment: There is no need of using `*` ?

Comment: @PabloCasas : There is no need for the `*`, no. Adding a `*` between `.secciones` and `input[type=text]` would actually select all descendants of `.secciones` of the type `input[type=text]` that are NOT direct descendants (children) of `.secciones`.